# bash: problem with looping through array of directory paths

Tags: bash, array, for

Array `arr1` contains two directory paths extracted with find command:

```
echo "${arr1[@]}"
/archive/logs/2020/02
/archive/raw/2020/02
```

I am testing if I can loop through the array `arr1` with this code:

```
for i in "${arr1[@]}"
do
echo Symlinking to $i
done
```

The output is:

```
Symlinking to /archive/logs/2020/02 /archive/raw/2020/02
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Symlinking to /archive/logs/2020/02
Symlinking to /archive/raw/2020/02
```

I also tried to put quotes around `$i` --> `echo Symlinking to "$i"` but still did not get the output that I expect.
How could I fix this?

Comment: @Quasímodo Nope, it looks like `arr1` is not an array at all.

Comment: Can you post declaration of arr1?

Comment: It looks to me like `arr1` has only one element (or isn't an array at all), and contains a newline character between the two paths. What does `declare -p arr1` print?

Comment: `for a in "${arr1[@]}"; do echo "> $a <"; done` will almost certainly demonstrate that you have one array element with two newline-separated items.

Comment: @roaima correct. how do i remove the new line separator then?

Comment: Better to update your question to show how you're creating the array, because i think that's really the problem here. Fix that and your expectation matches reality.

Comment: Better to check the contents of an array: `declare -p arr1`

Comment: [BashFAQ #20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) has recommendations for how to store `find` results in an array.